# Multiple dropdown to filter data using ajax php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 4 dropdowns through which i am filtering and printing the data from database. The issue is that if i only select the value of 1 dropdown it automatically put the default value of other dropdowns in the ajax function like.

### for example

```
dropdown 1    |   dropdown 2     | dropdown 3     | dropdown 4
  val_d1            val_d2           val_d3            val_d4
  val2_d1           val2_d2          val2_d3           val2_d4
  val3_d1           val3_d           val3_d3           val3_d4
```

Now if i select only value from dropdown 1 to filter data. It automatically select values from other dropdown.

What i want is if i select value from dropdown 1 only value of that dropdown should go in ajax.

```
  <section id="coup_filter">
       all dropdowns are inside this section
  <section>
```

### Here is my script

```
 $('#filter').on('change','.filter',function(){

            var bank;
            bank=$("select[name='bank']").val();
            var card_type;
            card_type=$("select[name='card_type']").val();
            var afee;
            afee=$("select[name='annual_fee']").val();
            var jfee;
            afee=$("select[name='joining_fee']").val();
            alert(card_type);
            load_data2();
            function load_data2(page){
            $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo site_url();?>/ajax/autoload_cc',
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: {
                        page: page,afee:afee,card_type:card_type,jfee:jfee,bank:bank
                    },
                    success: function(res){
                        var html;var i;
                        if(res.length==0)
                        {
                            html +='<h3>No Result Found</h3>';
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //print data
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like typo error afee / jfee

you have

```
afee=$("select[name='joining_fee']").val();
```

which should be

```
jfee=$("select[name='joining_fee']").val();
```